# Google Geochart are they free after 11th June 2018?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

They say charts are free:
https://developers.google.com/chart/

But geo charts do require a mapsApiKey
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

And starting 11th June they are charging for the usage of Google Maps API.

So are they free or not?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Google's terms of use and pricing, not coding.

Comment: Google Geochart doesn't form part of Google Maps Platform. It belongs to [Google Visualization API](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) which is part of Google Cloud Platform. So June 11th doesn't affect this API.

Comment: @xomenia then why does it require maps api key ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Google Geocharts will not longer be free (at least for new users), as even of today, I've got an error message

"Geocoding Service: You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API."

So geocharts usage counts (underlying geocoding request, but therefore probably also javascript map loads).

I've used the following code:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
     google.charts.load('current', {
       'packages': ['geochart'],        'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
     });
     google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);
      function drawMarkersMap() {
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['City',   'Crime Index' ],
  ['Townsville, Australia', 63.36],
  ['Catania, Italy', 58.13],
  ['Saint Petersburg, Russia', 40.85],
  ['Algiers, Algeria', 51.24],
  ['Florence, Italy', 34.57],
  ['Milan, Italy', 44.97],
  ['Cairo, Egypt', 55.88],
  ['Florianopolis, Brazil', 57.94],
  ['Rosario, Argentina', 67.45],
  ['Naples, Italy', 58.30],
  ['Baku, Azerbaijan', 26.75],
  ['Guadalajara, Mexico', 54.20],
  ['Mexico City, Mexico', 66.57],
  ['Mangalore, India', 24.68],
  ['Rome, Italy', 54.34],
  ['Monterrey, Mexico', 50.56],
  ['Sarajevo, Bosnia And Herzegovina', 46.75],
  ['Turin, Italy', 56.31],
  ['Puebla, Mexico', 61.13],
  ['Puerto Vallarta, Mexico', 30.17],
  ['Belgrade, Serbia', 36.95],
  ['Tijuana, Mexico', 51.57],
  ['Osaka, Japan', 16.77],
  ['Sofia, Bulgaria', 44.59],
  ['Novi Sad, Serbia', 44.12],
  ['Singapore, Singapore', 16.23],
  ['Tokyo, Japan', 16.86],
  ['Rijeka, Croatia', 19.46],
  ['Busan, South Korea', 39.49],
  ['Almaty, Kazakhstan', 50.06],
  ['San Salvador, El Salvador', 73.53],
  ['Bratislava, Slovakia', 30.69],
  ['Dhaka, Bangladesh', 70.57],
  ['Zagreb, Croatia', 26.01],
  ['Riga, Latvia', 37.96],
  ['Tehran, Iran', 53.79],
  ['Liverpool, United Kingdom', 39.38],
  ['Limassol, Cyprus', 34.10],
  ['Abu Dhabi, United Arab Emirates', 13.63],
  ['Incheon, South Korea', 39.82],
  ['Nicosia, Cyprus', 27.87],
  ['Dubai, United Arab Emirates', 19.03],
  ['Brno, Czech Republic', 28.38],
  ['Panama City, Panama', 48.35],
  ['Seoul, South Korea', 35.16],
  ['Johor Bahru, Malaysia', 60.23],
  ['Prague, Czech Republic', 27.55],
  ['Kuala Lumpur, Malaysia', 68.23],
  ['Phnom Penh, Cambodia', 55.86],
  ['Kuching, Malaysia', 50.08],
  ['Aalborg, Denmark', 19.77],
  ['Copenhagen, Denmark', 21.57],
  ['Petaling Jaya, Malaysia', 65.08],
  ['Bali, Indonesia', 42.46],
  ['Ljubljana, Slovenia', 24.97],
  ['Colombo, Sri Lanka', 37.48],
  ['Kaunas, Lithuania', 45.83],
  ['Baghdad, Iraq', 53.30],
  ['Male, Maldives', 65.18],
  ['Addis Ababa, Ethiopia', 44.74],
  ['Beijing, China', 48.09],
  ['Cape Town, South Africa', 69.88],
  ['Durban, South Africa', 79.21],
  ['Vilnius, Lithuania', 30.90],
  ['Johannesburg, South Africa', 78.86],
  ['Barcelona, Spain', 45.84],
  ['Port Elizabeth, South Africa', 73.19],
  ['Pretoria, South Africa', 78.52],
  ['Lima, Peru', 68.44],
  ['Guangzhou, China', 50.58],
  ['Ulaanbaatar, Mongolia', 60.22],
  ['Luxembourg, Luxembourg', 28.64],
  ['Madrid, Spain', 41.38],
  ['Tallinn, Estonia', 20.46],
  ['Haifa, Israel', 42.32],
  ['Valencia, Spain', 42.15],
  ['Navi Mumbai, India', 36.33],
  ['Tel Aviv-Yafo, Israel', 40.37],
  ['Taipei, Taiwan', 19.46],
  ['San Juan, Puerto Rico', 68.91],
  ['Belo Horizonte, Brazil', 69.09],
  ['Bangkok, Thailand', 47.06],
  ['Skopje, Macedonia', 45.65],
  ['Shanghai, China', 43.97],
  ['Lund, Sweden', 40.11],
  ['Chiang Mai, Thailand', 28.71],
  ['Shenzhen, China', 52.61],
  ['Campinas, Brazil', 65.97],
  ['Basel, Switzerland', 16.01],
  ['Bern, Switzerland', 17.24],
  ['Amman, Jordan', 41.99],
  ['Geneva, Switzerland', 26.47],
  ['Phuket, Thailand', 58.46],
  ['Stockholm, Sweden', 47.58],
  ['Buenos Aires, Argentina', 62.41],
  ['Casablanca, Morocco', 54.32],
  ['San Jose, Costa Rica', 53.14],
  ['Lausanne, Switzerland', 30.52],
  ['Curitiba, Brazil', 65.37],
  ['Dar Es Salaam, Tanzania', 64.38],
  ['Lodz, Poland', 48.38],
  ['Montreal, Canada', 33.40],
  ['Fortaleza, Brazil', 80.61],
  ['Sao Paulo, Brazil', 72.41],
  ['Gothenburg, Sweden', 41.87],
  ['Valenzuela, Philippines', 25.21],
  ['Queretaro, Mexico', 35.06],
  ['Zurich, Switzerland', 19.01],
  ['Stavanger, Norway', 41.69],
  ['Ankara, Turkey', 43.44],
  ['Medellin, Colombia', 45.39],
  ['Bursa, Turkey', 19.73],
  ['Pattaya, Thailand', 55.42],
  ['Jerusalem, Israel', 40.93],
  ['Eskisehir, Turkey', 21.07],
  ['Malaga, Spain', 43.86],
  ['Istanbul, Turkey', 50.35],
  ['Porto Alegre, Brazil', 77.07],
  ['Izmir, Turkey', 26.97],
  ['Helsinki, Finland', 24.42],
  ['Chisinau, Moldova', 44.43],
  ['Recife, Brazil', 77.47],
  ['Rio De Janeiro, Brazil', 76.98],
  ['Salvador, Brazil', 78.75],
  ['Kochi, India', 35.43],
  ['Oulu, Finland', 26.39],
  ['Kathmandu, Nepal', 36.00],
  ['Hanoi, Vietnam', 51.55],
  ['Cordoba, Argentina', 50.77],
  ['Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam', 56.50],
  ['Tampere, Finland', 23.15],
  ['Kuwait City, Kuwait', 35.86],
  ['Brampton, Canada', 54.66],
  ['Kharkiv, Ukraine', 46.77],
  ['Kiev, Ukraine', 47.90],
  ['Calgary, Canada', 32.40],
  ['Brasilia, Brazil', 64.44],
  ['Tunis, Tunisia', 36.72],
  ['Edmonton, Canada', 41.72],
  ['Port Of Spain, Trinidad And Tobago', 77.75],
  ['Hamilton, Canada', 44.99],
  ['Lyon, France', 38.31],
  ['Amsterdam, Netherlands', 33.67],
  ['Marseille, France', 64.35],
  ['Kelowna, Canada', 46.45],
  ['Halifax, Canada', 42.77],
  ['London, Canada', 46.96],
  ['Paris, France', 52.95],
  ['Mississauga, Canada', 45.97],
  ['Eindhoven, Netherlands', 24.32],
  ['Tromso, Norway', 52.48],
  ['Thessaloniki, Greece', 34.17],
  ['Ottawa, Canada', 23.95],
  ['Regina, Canada', 54.67],
  ['Toulouse, France', 41.85],
  ['Albuquerque, NM, United States', 68.06],
  ['Rotterdam, Netherlands', 36.36],
  ['Split, Croatia', 35.08],
  ['Saskatoon, Canada', 48.81],
  ['Windhoek, Namibia', 71.86],
  ['Atlanta, GA, United States', 64.99],
  ['Berlin, Germany', 40.97],
  ['Surrey, Canada', 63.27],
  ['Beirut, Lebanon', 49.91],
  ['Austin, TX, United States', 34.62],
  ['Auckland, New Zealand', 46.23],
  ['Toronto, Canada', 35.40],
  ['Bergen, Norway', 40.65],
  ['Vancouver, Canada', 35.96],
  ['Baltimore, MD, United States', 70.24],
  ['Bremen, Germany', 50.51],
  ['Christchurch, New Zealand', 38.13],
  ['Victoria, Canada', 32.92],
  ['Belfast, United Kingdom', 43.51],
  ['Winnipeg, Canada', 54.30],
  ['Boise, ID, United States', 31.45],
  ['Birmingham, United Kingdom', 52.84],
  ['Boston, MA, United States', 32.86],
  ['Cologne, Germany', 48.50],
  ['Kristiansand, Norway', 56.22],
  ['Charlotte, NC, United States', 41.56],
  ['Chicago, IL, United States', 65.37],
  ['Cincinnati, OH, United States', 48.24],
  ['Oslo, Norway', 44.01],
  ['Frankfurt, Germany', 45.54],
  ['Columbus, OH, United States', 45.10],
  ['Cardiff, United Kingdom', 38.78],
  ['Trondheim, Norway', 33.75],
  ['Dallas, TX, United States', 45.17],
  ['Denver, CO, United States', 37.78],
  ['Detroit, MI, United States', 71.43],
  ['Hamburg, Germany', 51.11],
  ['Krakow (Cracow), Poland', 35.98],
  ['Wellington, New Zealand', 29.92],
  ['Gdansk, Poland', 41.45],
  ['Waterloo, Canada', 24.01],
  ['Santiago, Chile', 49.66],
  ['Nairobi, Kenya', 59.94],
  ['Edinburgh, United Kingdom', 31.40],
  ['Merida, Mexico', 21.48],
  ['Glasgow, United Kingdom', 44.73],
  ['Honolulu, HI, United States', 41.73],
  ['Houston, TX, United States', 60.86],
  ['Tbilisi, Georgia', 19.81],
  ['Bogota, Colombia', 61.58],
  ['Muscat, Oman', 27.93],
  ['Poznan, Poland', 38.58],
  ['Munich, Germany', 17.45],
  ['Leeds, United Kingdom', 40.55],
  ['Kansas City, MO, United States', 60.12],
  ['Las Vegas, NV, United States', 55.17],
  ['Nuremberg, Germany', 39.00],
  ['The Hague (Den Haag), Netherlands', 29.59],
  ['London, United Kingdom', 47.75],
  ['Los Angeles, CA, United States', 48.43],
  ['Manchester, United Kingdom', 55.89],
  ['Newcastle Upon Tyne, United Kingdom', 38.30],
  ['Warsaw, Poland', 33.45],
  ['Miami, FL, United States', 54.19],
  ['Wroclaw, Poland', 41.25],
  ['Milwaukee, WI, United States', 63.34],
  ['Minneapolis, MN, United States', 49.12],
  ['Nottingham, United Kingdom', 40.37],
  ['New Orleans, LA, United States', 69.89],
  ['Lagos, Nigeria', 66.37],
  ['New York, NY, United States', 44.68],
  ['Dusseldorf, Germany', 29.63],
  ['Stuttgart, Germany', 27.70],
  ['Oakland, CA, United States', 66.29],
  ['Islamabad, Pakistan', 38.05],
  ['Chandigarh, India', 41.97],
  ['Orlando, FL, United States', 56.70],
  ['Karachi, Pakistan', 62.20],
  ['Athens, Greece', 49.56],
  ['Philadelphia, PA, United States', 58.53],
  ['Phoenix, AZ, United States', 56.73],
  ['Lahore, Pakistan', 46.90],
  ['Pittsburgh, PA, United States', 38.05],
  ['Hong Kong, Hong Kong', 20.90],
  ['Portland, OR, United States', 44.41],
  ['Lisbon, Portugal', 33.53],
  ['Richmond, VA, United States', 42.89],
  ['Porto, Portugal', 43.07],
  ['Riverside, CA, United States', 43.03],
  ['Tirana, Albania', 39.47],
  ['Rochester, NY, United States', 56.46],
  ['Sacramento, CA, United States', 47.81],
  ['Budapest, Hungary', 36.96],
  ['Saint Louis, MO, United States', 66.94],
  ['San Pedro Sula, Honduras', 85.18],
  ['Salt Lake City, UT, United States', 26.21],
  ['San Antonio, TX, United States', 47.33],
  ['Quebec City, Canada', 16.43],
  ['San Diego, CA, United States', 33.95],
  ['San Francisco, CA, United States', 49.16],
  ['San Jose, CA, United States', 46.61],
  ['Seattle, WA, United States', 43.71],
  ['Bucharest, Romania', 28.88],
  ['Ahmedabad, India', 40.49],
  ['Malmo, Sweden', 50.08],
  ['Tampa, FL, United States', 49.14],
  ['Cluj-Napoca, Romania', 23.03],
  ['Bangalore, India', 49.67],
  ['Washington, DC, United States', 57.50],
  ['Iasi, Romania', 26.69],
  ['Chennai, India', 42.12],
  ['Delhi, India', 59.34],
  ['Doha, Qatar', 14.48],
  ['Gurgaon, India', 64.99],
  ['Ad Dammam, Saudi Arabia', 52.01],
  ['Hyderabad, India', 37.99],
  ['Vienna, Austria', 22.62],
  ['Montevideo, Uruguay', 55.89],
  ['Kingston, Jamaica', 70.30],
  ['Tripoli, Libya', 59.60],
  ['Timisoara, Romania', 23.34],
  ['Kolkata, India', 49.71],
  ['Jeddah (Jiddah), Saudi Arabia', 48.81],
  ['Port Moresby, Papua New Guinea', 80.68],
  ['Mumbai, India', 44.52],
  ['Riyadh, Saudi Arabia', 33.35],
  ['Nagpur, India', 37.84],
  ['Reykjavik, Iceland', 21.78],
  ['Pune, India', 41.78],
  ['Baguio, Philippines', 40.57],
  ['Caracas, Venezuela', 82.55],
  ['Cancun, Mexico', 38.32],
  ['Harare, Zimbabwe', 52.43],
  ['Minsk, Belarus', 25.88],
  ['Surat, India', 41.57],
  ['Vadodara, India', 38.83],
  ['Cebu, Philippines', 44.28],
  ['Cork, Ireland', 29.19],
  ['Visakhapatnam, India', 40.62],
  ['Davao, Philippines', 28.79],
  ['Dublin, Ireland', 50.64],
  ['Iloilo, Philippines', 48.76],
  ['Moscow, Russia', 45.98],
  ['Penang, Malaysia', 45.00],
  ['Galway, Ireland', 28.06],
  ['Santo Domingo, Dominican Republic', 67.17],
  ['Limerick, Ireland', 39.10],
  ['Makati, Philippines', 39.56],
  ['Adelaide, Australia', 34.26],
  ['Damascus, Syria', 64.64],
  ['Yerevan, Armenia', 29.88],
  ['Manila, Philippines', 59.17],
  ['Jakarta, Indonesia', 53.14],
  ['Brisbane, Australia', 34.87],
  ['Cuenca, Ecuador', 38.41],
  ['Canberra, Australia', 21.18],
  ['Darwin, Australia', 63.08],
  ['Antwerp, Belgium', 38.37],
  ['Manama, Bahrain', 29.42],
  ['Gold Coast, Australia', 42.84],
  ['Lviv, Ukraine', 39.92],
  ['Novosibirsk, Russia', 47.15],
  ['Quezon City, Philippines', 60.30],
  ['Hobart, Australia', 34.15],
  ['Brussels, Belgium', 51.31],
  ['Melbourne, Australia', 42.36],
  ['Perth, Australia', 43.93],
  ['Gent, Belgium', 24.68],
  ['Bologna, Italy', 43.70],
  ['Sydney, Australia', 38.24],
  ['Alexandria, Egypt', 52.52],
  ['Quito, Ecuador', 53.54]      ]);

      var options = {
        displayMode: 'markers',
        colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    };
```